# How do I manage mysql query errors from express in a React form?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

I am trying to send users to two different pages based on whether an SQL query is successful or not on an express backend. But only the success route is showing when I use this code.

I previously did not have the await statement in, but had the same issue. I'm not sure whether the react side is taking in the error message as a response, as it's still logging into the console from the backend.

Here is the method in the frontend which is called when the form is submitted:

````
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);  
        const newPost = {
            pet_name : this.state.pet_name, 
            content : this.state.content, 
            content : this.state.content, 
            owner : 'testOwner', 
            email : 'test@gmail.com', 
            img_path : this.state.upload_image
        }; 
        //fetch instead of this to talk about in diss

        try {
        const postData = await axios.post('http://localhost:3306/reportpet', newPost)
        .then(res=>console.log(res.data));
        this.props.history.push('/postsubmitted')

        } catch(error) { 
            console.log("Catch = ", error.response); 
            this.props.history.push('/posterror')

    }```

The route on the backend is as follows: 
```router.post('/reportpet', function (req, res) {

    var pet_name = req.body.pet_name,
    content = req.body.content,
    date = req.body.date,
    owner = req.body.owner,
    email = req.body.email,
    img_path = req.body.img_path;  

    const query = "INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `pet_name`, `content`, `date`, `owner`, `email`, `img_path`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, UTC_TIMESTAMP(),?, ?, ?);"
    console.log(query);
    connection.query(query, [pet_name, pet_name, content, owner, email, img_path ], function(err, result) {
        (err)?res.send(err+'error was created'):res.json(result); 
        if (err) throw err; 
        console.log('rows inserted')
    })

})

module.exports = router
````

When the data is not added to the database, I expect the user to be sent to the error component. When it is successful, I expect the success component to display.

Answer (score 0):

Try to skip using .then() in await.
And be sure that your backend returns the response with proper HTTP error code (4xx or 5xx) so the axios knows that error happened.

```
try {
    const postData = await axios.post('http://localhost:3306/reportpet', newPost)

    console.log(postData);

    this.props.history.push('/postsubmitted')
} catch(error) { 
    console.log("Catch = ", error.response); 
    this.props.history.push('/posterror')
}
```

Comment: It still seems to go straight to the success page. The console prints this: 
```
{data: "Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'pet_name' cannot be nullerror was created", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```
But we never get to /posterror

Comment: You had status 200 which is a success status code, which is why axios didn't throw an error.

And as I can see you send the error result to front-end before throw the error
`(err) ? res.send(err+'error was created') : res.json(result); if (err) throw err;`. Try to rewrite this to `if (err) throw err; res.json(result);`

Comment: That's awesome! It's working now! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Mykola Prymak answered this. I had a response sending the error instead of throwing it, removing that and adding the response underneath the throw fixed it.

Code in the backend is now this:

````
const query = "INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `pet_name`, `content`, `date`, `owner`, `email`, `img_path`) VALUES (null, ?, ?, UTC_TIMESTAMP(),?, ?, ?);"
    console.log(query);
    connection.query(query, [pet_name, content, owner, email, img_path ], function(err, result) {
        // (err)?res.send(err+'error was created'):res.json(result); {removed code}
        if (err) throw err; 
        res.json(result); 
        console.log('rows inserted')
    })
    ```
````